# For every square matrix A, does there always exists a non diagonal matrix B such that AB=BA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For every square matrix $A$, does there always exists a non diagonal matrix $B$ such that AB=BA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, no, not if $A$ is diagonal with all distinct diagonal entries.

The simplest way to state the relevant theorem is this: for a square matrix $M,$ if the characteristic polynomial of $M$ and the minimal polynomial of $M$ are the same, then the only matrices that commute with $M$ are polynomials in $M,$ that is 
$$ w_0 I + w_1 M + w_2 M^2 + \cdots + w_{n-1} M^{n-1},  $$ when
$M$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix. We do not need to use degree $n$ or higher because of Cayley-Hamilton.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.

However, when $A$ is not diagonal, the answer is yes, since $B=A$ satisfies $B$ is not diagonal and $AB=BA$.

Consider

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and any

$$B=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then

$$AB=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

but

$$BA=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b \\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so if $AB=BA$, $b=c=0$, forcing $B$ to be diagonal.